# Removing Minecarts in 1.7.10 using command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to remove Minecarts from a map using command blocks in 1.7.10?

Comment: Why 1.7.10? I'm asking because I have a feeling it's related to mods, in which case there might be a mod config type solution. Also, is this a one-time thing (i.e. delete all existing Minecarts in the game) or do you want to permanently disable minecarts?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
/kill @e[type=MinecartRideable]
```

In a command block. That should do it!

Comment: The `@e` selector was not added until 1.8.