# Removing Minecarts from map in 1.7.10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a timer in my adventure map that uses Minecarts. I would like for the timer to be able to start and stop as needed. How would I remove Minecarts from a map using command blocks in 1.7.10. I am also open to other redstone ideas on how to remove the Minecart.

Comment: Duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254810/removing-minecarts-in-1-7-10-using-command-blocks?rq=1, but that one is unanswered.

Comment: *" I am also open to other redstone ideas on how to remove the Minecart"* - would this include things like dropping them in lava?

Comment: @colorfusion yes that is what I meant. Which now actually gives me an idea. But I am still looking for a way to remove them with command blocks (if there is even a way).

Answer (score -2):

You can target entities with the @e selector, and only minecarts with the Type Argument.

Example: @e[type=MinecartRideable] 
NOTE: Each minecart has a different Type.

Note: the @e selector was introduced in 1.8.

Comment: -1 the selectors were added in 1.8